# How to embed Neo4j Graph in a webpage ?

Tags: php, graph, neo4j, embed, html

I have been trying to embed the Neo4j Graphs that I am able to see in the Neo4j browser, in a web application.

I was initially taking reference from this website. 
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-php-neoclient
and 
http://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/#_example_project_description

These github examples don't seem to run. Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clearly explain the problem you're having.

Anyway, this file `static/movies.cypher` in the source folder of the Github repo  has been changed from [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j-examples/movies-php-neoclient/290f35daff2c4b63a5096c9c9fab99d12343b937/static/movies.cypher) to a mere 15 line code. But that has made it inconsistent with the other files. So basically yeah, the project is broken.
Your page must be looking blank like this:

[image]

Now you can copy-paste the contents from the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j-examples/movies-php-neoclient/290f35daff2c4b63a5096c9c9fab99d12343b937/static/movies.cypher) into your local `static/movies.cypher` file and it should look similar to [this site](http://my-neo4j-movies-app.herokuapp.com/). 
Alternatively, you can replace `Actor` with `Person` and `ACTS_IN` with `ACTED_IN` in that file and you'll get a smaller six node graph instead.

You might need these two links too:

- `http://localhost:8080/reset` 
  This will delete the existing graph and try to re-import it.
  You'll need to use it after everytime you modify the `static/movies.cypher` file.
- `http://localhost:8080/import`
  This will import the `statics/movies.cypher` and execute it. 
  So basically it'll re-create the graph.